# Parsing code-model from in-memory C#-code string

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, projectitem, c#-code-model

With `EnvDTE.ProjectItem`, is it possible to parse an in-memory C#-code string to get the `FileCodeModel`?

I don't want to alter the project file in this course by adding a temporary file to project, get its `ProjectItem`, do stuff and then delete the file. It will further alert the source control to observe the changes.

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no good way to do this with CodeModel. This is why we're building Roslyn to make this sort of operation trivial -- it operates with an immutable model where you can take a solution, fork it to a separate copy and do analysis, without every modifying the original. There's [previews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/roslyn) out you might be able to use, depending upon your scenario.

Comment: The Roslyn code is vast. Can you please narrow it down and point me to the part where it take C#/VB code-string and return code model? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve?